# When put into drive, the car makes a click/crunch noise after a second

Tags: honda, noise, automatic-transmission, accord, drivetrain

2006 Honda Accord with almost 230K miles. When put into drive, the car makes a click about a second after the gear is put into drive. What could this be? Car drives and shift with no problem.

Comment: Roughly where is the noise coming from?  Inside/outside, front/rear, engine compartment, wheels?

Comment: @HandyHowie sounds like the engine bay, down low. Somewhere behind the steering wheel.

Comment: If you keep your foot on the brake, then repeatedly switch between drive and reverse, do you keep getting the clicking noise when selecting drive?